# Error : 401 during request call from MSGraph SDK for iOS

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I am using "MSGraphSDK-NXOAuth2Adapter" as OAuth2 for integrating MSGraph SDK in my native iOS Application.
After the app being idle for some minutes or when i put application to background and then bring it to foreground, each service call giving me 401 as error.

Is there anyone who had faced such issue with MSGraphSDK earlier? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Today I got the same error: Graph SDK ERROR : Error from data task : Error Domain=com.microsoft.graph. errors Code=401 "unauthorized" UserInfo={error= InvalidAuthenticationToken : Access token has expired., NSLocalizedDescription=unauthorized}.

It means we need refresh token. I'm still working on it.

Comment: add some codes here:

if (identifier) {
        for (NXOAuth2Account *account in [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] accounts]) {
            if ([account.identifier isEqualToString:identifier] && account.accessToken.refreshToken) {
                self.userAccount = account;
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }

When refreashToken expired, it will request accessToken again.